# Test for incoming connections

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, low-level

I've been thinking about that for a while, but can not figure out how to do that :

I would like to have a way to know if someone tries to connect to some of my port, but without opening it :

For example, let's say we are talking about port 9999.

I want it to look closed, but I want to know when someone tries to connect.

I thought about `syn`/`ack`, but can't figure out a way to do that, as most of the tools, we have (such as nc) or libs on certain languages (sys/socket.h for c, for example), but they are more higher levels, and do not let us use low level sockets.

I'm working on Linux. Please help

Comment: use an utility that does this (like `tcpdump`, `iptables`, `tcpflow` etc.) and use `strace` to see what sys calls they do.

Comment: If you don't open the port behind a NAT then your router won't know where to forward the request to. Your firewall might block it too.

Comment: What about sending a RST to respond to a SYN, or an ICMP deny? You could either just have the connections logged by the firewall directly, or attach a program to an NFQUEUE.

Comment: `tcpdump/wireshark` use the pcap lib that has lots of helper functions. But, under the hood they open a `PF_PACKET` socket and `bind`it to a network _interface_ (e.g. `eth0`). Then, they "snoop" a copy of _any_ packet that comes/goes on the interface. The packet buffer has headers from _all_ network layers